# Solving the linear ordinary differential equation $x\,dy = (ax+by)\,dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What I've tried so far:
Express in form $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ax+by}{x}$
Make substitution $y = zx \implies \frac{xdz}{dx} + z = a + bz$
Which leads to equality $\int \frac{dz}{a + (b-1)z} = \int \frac{dx}{x}$
That leads us to $\frac{1}{b-1} \ln (|a + (b-1) \frac{y}{x}|) - ln(x) = C$

So I am curious what to do next (assuming my previous steps were correct)? And what the final answer should look like? Some equality $y = f(x, a, b, c)$? Thank you in advance

Comment: let $C$ be $\ln(C)$

Comment: Next you need to isolate $y$ in order to determine $y(x)$.

Comment: Instead of "guessing" an adequate change of variable, since it is a nonhomogeneous first-order linear ODE, you may solve the associated homogeneous problem at first and add a particular solution with the help of the method of the variation of parameter, as described in the dedicated Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Alternatively, the substitution $y := x^b z$ transforms the equation to
$$z' = a x^b,$$
which can be integrated immediately. Be sure to handle separately the case $b = -1$.

(You can derive this change of variable algorithmically by noticing that the original equation is first-order and linear, $y' -\frac{b}{x} y = a$, and so it can be integrated after multiplying through by the integrating factor $\exp \int_1^x -\frac{b}{t} \,dt = x^b.$)